# Neo4j - Cypher Reflexive Relationship Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How can I write reflexive relationship query using `Cypher`? For example, I have defined a directional relationship named `follows` which is used between `User` nodes. What I am looking for is **finding the users that follow each other**.

Here is what I have tried:

```
MATCH (x:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(y:User), y-[:FOLLOWS]->x
```

Detail regarding `Neo4j`:

Version: `3.5.2`

Edition: `Community`

Answer (score 0):

The terminology for this is a relationship, not a property, though yes you can look for users who follow each other. Something like:

```
MATCH (x:User)-[:FOLLOWS]->(y:User)
WHERE id(x) < id(y) AND (y)-[:FOLLOWS]->(x)
RETURN x, y
```

The id predicate here is to ensure you only see each pairing once, and not an additional time for the same pairing in opposite order.

Comment: This query returns an odd number of relationships?

Comment: The query makes sure you don't get the same pair of `User` nodes twice (e.g., you won't get `Fred, Ethel` and `Ethel, Fred`).